# Is there any way to embed video from another website on linkedin?

Tags: php, html, laravel, linkedin-api

I need to embed a video from my website and be playable on Linkedin.
I tried to make an iframe in my view and then post the URL on Linkedin. When I click on the thumbnail, it redirects me to my website instead of playing the video on Linkedin.

I need it to be like Youtube on posting a link from youtube and try to play it, it plays in Linkedin.

Here is my view code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Video embed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://example.com/path-to-video.mp4" frameborde ="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay;"
            allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**UPDATES**

I tried the following code too and still doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML Video embed</title>

    <meta property="og:video" content="https://example/path-to-video.mp4" />
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://example/path-to-video.mp4" />
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="400" />
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="300" />

</head>
<body>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src=https://example/path-to-video.mp4"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
        allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd suspect this happens via `og:video` tags. https://ogp.me/ See `og:video:secure_url`, `og:video:type`, `og:video:width`, etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz I tried this too and still doesn't work, check the updates please